# Recover windows seven

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I started on Ubuntu and have had the first considerable error. I'm looking for help.
I have an HP Pavilion dv6 i7. I had installed windows 7 and I decided to also install Ubuntu using a USB.

My first attempt was to install Ubuntu 11.10 following the instructions of the official Ubuntu website. When loading the pendrive, my PC stucks at the main menu of ubuntu, so after searching, I found could be due to a problem with my AMD Radeon graphic card (or not), but I decided to change.

Then I used Ubuntu 10.4. This could happen from the start menu i get into Ubuntu live. There I decided to install it because I liked it and I need to develope with Google TV (in windows is not posible).

And I fail in the partitions section. I tried to follow the instructions on this page:

http://hadesbego.blogspot.com/2010/08/instalando-linux-en-hp-pavilion-dv6.html

but there were things that changed a bit so I improvised. I took the windows partition of 700000MB and went to 600000Mb leaving 100GB free to install Linux there. The error was to set it to ext3 (it was ntfs). I thought the new 100gb partition will be set to ext3, and windows partition will stuck at ntfs system, but not.

Total I ran out to boot windows, and above I can not install ubuntu on the 100GB free.

Someone thinks I can help. Is there any easy way to convert back to ntfs windows and not lose data?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question - it'd be better suited to SuperUser...

Comment: uou. I didn't know that page. Thanks, and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hit F11 when the machine is booting up and go to the HP recovery application. This should let you reset to factory default.

You should definitely be able to install Ubuntu on the new 100GB partition as well. Just make sure you choose the right partition to install it on.

Comment: I can't acces to HP recovery application. It says this: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-bLkBNJcjAV0/TXT4MXdc0II/AAAAAAAAABs/IsNf1Xi3zgw/s1600/bootmanager.jpg

Comment: Hmm, looks like you've even messed up the recovery partition! You will have to try and get your hands on a Win7 recovery disk.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to recover using recovery CD/DVD's. You must have been using the install gparted utility in Linux to "re-partition" your drive. You scrubbed some boot files.

If you successfully recover using the recovery media you can use Disk Management in Win 7 to shrink or extend your volume. In your case you would shrink it down 100Gb's and then when installing Linux gparted will see that available 100 GB and install there while Windows will still run.

Also, you should probably be running ext4 fs, not ext3. you would only want ext3 for compatibility reasons.

Comment: ok. thanks. There's a problem, another. I use the win7 dvd to recover it, but in it doesn't appear any SO to recover, because it is in ext3, and windows doesn't recognize that type. I'm thinking about use gparted, in ubuntu live (which is the only thing I can load, at the moment) to pas the windows partition to ext3 back to ntfs again. But I not sure about my data. It will be lost...?

Comment: If your Win partition, the 600Gb partition was formatted from NTFS to ext3 that would have erased your data on the larger 600Gb partition. I think that is what your saying.